# How to break out a loop contains only a constrained execution region (CER)

Tags: c#, multithreading, constrained-execution-reg

I'm using a constrained execution region (CER) to protect the section of code within a while loop of a thread:

```
private static void MyThreadFunc()
{
    try {
        ...
        while (true)
        {
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
            try { }
            finally
            {
                // do something not to be aborted
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);    // allow while loop to be broken out
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException e)
    {
         // handle the exception 
    }
}
```

The problem is if I do not introduce the `Thread.Sleep(1)` statement at the end of the while loop, any attempt to call Thread.Abort() on the thread hangs.  Is there any better method to abort the thread without using the `Thread.Sleep()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need to abort the thread manually as CLR will do it once it's completed or use [Thread.Join](http://www.dotnetperls.com/thread-join) to wait until it terminates. But you can make use of the [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) to abort it gracefully.

I have made few changes in the code by replacing the **while(true)** with the [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class ThreadManager
{
    private ManualResetEvent shutdown = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private Thread thread;

    public void start ()
    {
        thread = new Thread(MyThreadFunc);
        thread.Name = "MyThreadFunc";
        thread.IsBackground = true; 
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop ()
    {
        shutdown.Set();
        if (!thread.Join(2000)) //2 sec to stop 
        { 
            thread.Abort();
        }
    }

    void MyThreadFunc ()
    {
        while (!shutdown.WaitOne(0))
        {
            // call with the work you need to do
            try {
                    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
                    try { }
                    finally
                    {
                        // do something not to be aborted
                    }
                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException e)
                {
                        // handle the exception 
                }
        }
    }
}
```